# Taxonomy Terms List and Features

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, features

I noticed that, while I am able to build taxonomy into my feature, it doesn't seem to include the list of terms within the taxonomy. When I go to create a feature, the `uuid_term` section does list a few, but not many, actual terms for me to select. What am I missing? It's worth mentioning that I am starting with a Demo build and customizing from there. The only terms that are actually listed are not showing up in Structure > Taxonomy.

I tried upgrading UUID to no avail.

Drupal 7.54
UUID 7.x-1.0
Features 7.x-2.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have Features, UUID and UUID Features modules enabled. In the uuid_features configuration, `admin/structure/features/uuid_features`, select " Auto detect uuid terms. When exporting a vocabulary, include its terms."

[image]

Comment: I would not recommend putting terms in features. Unless you have a reason to do so.

Comment: My reason is that terms will not change much, if all, after launch and I'm using GIT to deploy from my laptop to the test and production servers. I don't want to recreate giant lists of terms once they've already been checked and approved in order to minimize error and maximize efficiency. The editors that are growing the data and adding content do not have access to taxonomy. Can you expand?